After resampling, how to get the time matrix corresponding to RMS matrix using Librosa?
As the default sampling rate in Librosa is 22050, I want to downsample to sampling rate = 1000. However, after I resampled to sampling rate = 1000, the time_end is changing from 93.72s to around 4s, but I want the time_end to stay the same. In addition, I am having trouble getting the time matrix corresponding to RMS matrix. Currently I've used times_like and get_duration, but while librosa.get_duration returns the correct time length 93.72s, librosa.times_like(rmsmatrix) return a time series like this:
[0.00000000e+00 2.32199546e-02 4.64399093e-02 ... 2.18197914e+03
 2.18200236e+03 2.18202558e+03]

Here is my current code.

y_8k, sr2 = librosa.load('104.mp4', sr=1000)
time104 = librosa.get_duration(y=y_8k, sr=sr2)
print(time104) # Here prints 93.972s, which is the actual length of the audio file 104.mp4.
timematrix = librosa.times_like(rms104) # Here prints the time series shown above



I also tried calculating frame_length and hop_length to get the desired RMS matrix length, but I still don't know how to get the corresponding time matrix, as the librosa.times_like returns the correct number of datapoints, but the time_end is not 93.972s.

total_samples = len(y_8k)  
desired_rms_length = 93599   # Desired length 

hop_length1 = total_samples // desired_rms_length

frame_length1 = 2 * hop_length1
rms104 = librosa.feature.rms(y=y_8k, frame_length=frame_length1, hop_length=hop_length1)


I am confused on how to fix this. Can anyone kindly help me please?

librosa.times_like takes a parameter sr, which must be set to the samplerate of the input data. Otherwise, the default of 22050 is used, which give incorrect results. The same goes for hop_length.

Thanks for your help! I tried time104 = librosa.times_like(y_8k, sr = 1000) just now, but it's giving me the below matrix: [0.0000000e+00 5.1200000e-01 1.0240000e+00 ... 4.8112128e+04 4.8112640e+04
4.8113152e+04] It doesn't look like the time_end is 93.72s.

You did not pass hop_length. Also, surely you want to pass rms104, not y_8k ?
